# InterlockedCompareExchangePointer with Delphi string

Tags: multithreading, delphi

In my server code I use the following pattern for creating "just in time" objects:

```
function TSomeObject.GetChildObjects: TChildObjects;
var
  ChildObjects: TChildObjects;
begin
  if FChildObjects=nil then
    begin
      ChildObjects:=TChildObjects.Create;
// Fill child objects here
      if InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(Pointer(FChildObjects),ChildObjects,nil) <> nil then
        ChildObjects.Free;
    end;
  result:=FChildObjects;
end;
```

This works fine, but how would I do something similar with Delphi strings? e.g. if I wanted to initialise a string "just in time" in a multi threaded envrionment? Or do I have to use a critical section? e.g:

```
function TSomeObject.GetSomeString: string;
var
  s :string;
begin
  if FSomeString='' then
    begin
      s:='Test';
//      InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(Pointer(FSomeString),s,nil);
    end;
  result:=FSomeString;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are reference counted, so it is not enough to just swap the pointers, you have to manage the reference counts too, eg:

```pascal
function GetStrRec(const S: string): PStrRec; inline;
begin
  Result := PStrRec(PByte(S) - SizeOf(StrRec));
end;

function InterlockedCompareExchangeString(var VTarget: String; const AValue, Compare: String): String; inline;
var
  P: PStrRec;
begin
  Result := '';
  if AValue <> '' then begin
    P := GetStrRec(AValue);
    if P.refCnt > -1 then AtomicIncrement(P.refCnt);
  end;
  Pointer(Result) := InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(Pointer(VTarget), Pointer(AValue), Pointer(Compare));
  if Pointer(Result) <> Pointer(Compare) then begin
    if Result <> '' then begin
      P := GetStrRec(Result);
      if P.refCnt > -1 then AtomicIncrement(P.refCnt);
    end;
    if AValue <> '' then begin
      P := GetStrRec(AValue);
      if P.refCnt > -1 then AtomicDecrement(P.refCnt);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function GetStrRec(const S: string): PStrRec; inline;
begin
  Result := PStrRec(PByte(S) - SizeOf(StrRec));
end;

function InterlockedCompareExchangeString(var VTarget: String; const AValue, Compare: String): String; inline;
var
  P: PStrRec;
begin
  Result := '';
  Pointer(Result) := InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(Pointer(VTarget), Pointer(AValue), Pointer(Compare));
  if Pointer(Result) = Pointer(Comparand) then
  begin
    if AValue <> '' then begin
      P := GetStrRec(AValue);
      if P.refCnt > -1 then AtomicIncrement(P.refCnt);
    end;
  end
  else if Result <> '' then begin
    P := GetStrRec(Result);
    if P.refCnt > -1 then AtomicIncrement(P.refCnt);
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately, the RTL doesn't expose functions to manipulate a string's reference count, only to query it ([`StringRefCount()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StringRefCount)), which is why you have to access and manipulate the string's inner [`StrRec`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.StrRec) header manually.

Comment: This routine is defective and creates a memory leak or potentially causes an AV if a const string is being passed. strings cannot be exchanged atomically. It requires three operations (old value dec ref, new value inc ref, pointer swap) that need to be executed under a lock.

Comment: @StefanGlienke This example was adapted from other code I have that interlock-exchanges ref-counted interfaces, and ref-counted object pointers under ARC (which itself was adapted from RTL code for that purpose). But you are correct that I didn't account for string literals, which have a static refcount of -1. I have updated the code to handle that condition now. But, if you look at the RTL's own code for how it handles ref-counted strings, only the increment/decrement of the `StrRec.refCnt` field is executed under a `LOCK`, no other operations that manipulate string pointers are `LOCK`'ed.

Comment: Which is why string assignments are not thread-safe. Only their reference count is. If you do string or interface assignment without a lock you always have some potential race conditions - there is no way around this. FWIW the code in your answer is still defective because if the swap was executed it now leaks the string that was in VTarget before. The hardcast to string of the pointer result from the function is causing a string assignment which bumps the reference count. Also inside the function the refcount from AValue cannot drop to 0 - otherwise the caller would have dangling string.

Comment: @StefanGlienke "*FWIW the code in your answer is still defective because ...*" - updated